# DNN Can`t add reference

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I am using Christoc DotNetNuke Module and Theme Development Template to create new module for DNN 7 and try to add reference to my external .dll file.

I am able to access my library, I have intellisense, everything seem's to be ok, but when I build my solution, it give's me an error:

> The type or namespace name 'DllName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In same solution, I was add reference with `Nuget` console and everything works fine. I thing the problem is in Build Script, especially in Module Package targets but I can't figure it out.

Tested my library in other project (not DNN, just pure asp.net) and works fine.

Someone help?

Comment: Are you telling the project to make a local copy of the reference?

Comment: Hi Chris , glad to see you in this topic.. If you ask about "Copy local" in reference , yes it is True.. I made some screenshots : [screen1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnqawu8t84gmick/DNN%201.jpg?dl=0) , [screen2](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=DNN+2.jpg) , [screen3](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=DNN+3.jpg) . I hope you can help me.. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Mind posting them somewhere that you don't have to login?

Comment: http://smartit.bg/DNN1.jpg  ;   http://smartit.bg/DNN2.jpg   http://smartit.bg/DNN3.jpg .. Can you see them now ?

Comment: What does the references folder look like when this occurs?

Comment: Here it is : http://smartit.bg/dnn4.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in target framework of external lib . It was .net 4.5 , but module is on 4.0 , so that was the problem. Recompiled lib in 4.0 , add it again and everything works fine now. Thank you all for the help